# No "inspect" link chromecast 4th gen

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-tv

Thinking this may be a new issue with the updated chromecast device. My chromecast device is listed as attached in the terminal (IP address), I can cast an app + watch video, and the device shows at chrome://inspect/#devices. However, the device's "inspect" link isn't showing. I've tried restarting, killing the server, etc., but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

I've also enabled developer options and turned on usb debugging in Chromecast settings.

Comment: We're a coding support site. Your question is off topic.

Comment: I disagree. Many similar questions are present on the site regarding the earlier hardware. It's important for devs to be able to access the debugging tools.

Answer (score 0):

Did you allowlist your device in the developer console under the receiver? Please do allowlist the device and then try again. We did receive some issue regarding this and you can follow this bug for any updates: https://issuetracker.google.com/191684319

Answer (score 0):

After enabling developer settings in the Chromecast, connect this to your pc using a USB cable, just like with an Android phone.

[inspected chromecast using devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BVzW.jpg)